# require_once works without include path

Tags: php, require-once

I have file 1.php having a require_once for 2.php (both of them are in different folders). The issue I am having is that 1.php seems to magically include 2.php since the path for 2.php is not in 1.php. Just to be sure, I even added a set_include_path('.') before the require_once '2.php', but it still works... Is there something obvious I am missing or is this plain weird??

Edit:

```
//-- file 1.php
//-- long list of requires...
set_include_path('.');
echo get_include_path();
require_once '2.php';
```

The above works fine while 1.php and 2.php are in different folders.

Comment: Please be more specific on the locations of all the files involved.

Comment: Got any code you can add? It does seem odd.

Comment: @VolkerK - here we have only two files 1.php and 2.php and they are in two different locations..

@Kevin - added the code..

thanks for the comments..

Comment: "different locations" like what?  Like `/home/www/lala/1.php` and `/var/temp/2.php` ?

Comment: different locations like /var/www/test/1.php and /var/www/test/abcd/2.php... can you explain how that is relevant??

Comment: Only a prepended `..`? Can be anything, .. applies anywhere. Different paths with arbitrary parts? Needs some (specific) doing.

Comment: ...and you've accepted the answer where the actual paths would matter. Just nagging ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some include magic in PHP, i've met it before.
Something autoload related, I believe.
It always looks in the folder where file with running class resides

Comment: hmmm.. this looks interesting... where do i start looking for any autoload magic???

Comment: @pinaki dunno, I was looking into source code lol :) In some PHP OOP manual probably, because autoload is OOP feature

Answer (score 1):

Try `echo get_include_path()` after you set your empty include path, it may be set somewhere else (like in the web server config file).

Comment: there was a typo in the description... i have tried putting an echo get_include_path().. it lists the set path (.) in my case..

Answer (score 1):

Long shot but maybe one of the other included files changed the current working directory:

```
<?php
echo 'cwd at the beginning of 1.php: ', getcwd(), "\n";
//-- file 1.php
//-- long list of requires...
set_include_path('.');
echo 'include_path: ', get_include_path(), " \n";
echo 'cwd: ', getcwd(), "\n";
require_once '2.php';
```

Comment: `require` and `include` work with the current working dir when looking for files. So, if a script sets the cwd to the folder of 2.php (as VolkerK suggested), the seen behaviour would occur. Another option would be, that `1.php` gets included by a script living in the folder of `2.php`, so the cwd is there due to the initial invoke.

Comment: @ZeissS - i already did an echo getcwd() inside 2.php and that is not the case here...

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of argument, if you put a 2.php in the same location as 1.php does the new file get included instead of the old one?

Can you tell use what the value of your `open_basedir` is?

Comment: if i put them in the same place, it works fine.. open_basedir value in "no value"... i tried changing from 2.php to pinaki/2.php in the require_once and it failed... at last some sanity :)...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a file with the same name as file 2 in the path of file 1.